# Error de CORS al conectarme con un backend en producción (no me funciona la solución encontrada)

Tags: angular, cors

Estoy tratando de conectarme desde localhost, a través de una aplicación de Angular, con un backend que provee una serie de API REST que necesito consumir desde mi aplicación.

Desde Postman no tengo ningún problema, soy capaz de ver los datos de respuesta, con lo que la llamada a las API están bien construidas. El problema está del lado de Angular.

Como no tengo acceso al servidor para permitir peticiones desde localhost, he intentado hacer un proxy para saltarme este error, sin resultados satisfactorios.

¿Podéis decirme qué estoy haciendo mal aquí? El código lo he sacado de otra respuesta.

1. **environment.ts**:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  base_ayuntamiento: '/api'
};
```

2. **proxy.conf.json**:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://datos.madrid.es",
    "secure": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
    "^/posts": ""
     },
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

3. **actividades-ayuntamiento.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/* Operadores de RXJS */
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

/* Para poder realizar peticiones http */
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

/* URL base para las peticiones Ayuntamiento de Madrid */
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment'; 
const URL_BASE = environment.base_ayuntamiento;

/* Interfaz de respuesta eventos Ayuntamiento de Madrid */
import { EventosAyuntamiento } from '../interfaces/eventos-ayuntamiento.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ActividadesAyuntamientoService {
  /* Actividades del Ayuntamiento de Madrid */
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){
    /* Para poder realizar peticiones http */
  }

  proximasActividadesAyuntamiento(){
    return this.http.get<EventosAyuntamiento>('/api')
      .pipe(
        map(resp => {
          return resp['@graph'];
        })
      );      
  } 
}
```

4. **ayuntamiento-inicio.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

/* Servicio para consultar las últimas actividades e interfaz de respuesta */
import { ActividadesAyuntamientoService } from '../../services/actividades-ayuntamiento.service';
import { Graph } from '../../interfaces/eventos-ayuntamiento.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inicio-ayuntamiento',
  templateUrl: './ayuntamiento-inicio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ayuntamiento-inicio.component.css']
})
export class AyuntamientoInicioComponent implements OnInit {
  // Últimas actividades del ayuntamiento de Madrid
  actividades: Graph[];

  constructor(private actividadesService: ActividadesAyuntamientoService) {
    /* Inyección de dependencia */
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.actividadesService.proximasActividadesAyuntamiento()
        .subscribe( 
          (resp: Graph[]) => this.actividades = resp
        );
  }
}
```

Esta es la llamada que estoy haciendo desde Postman que, como podéis ver, funciona:

[image: Respuesta de Postman]

**AMPLIACIÓN DE LA PREGUNTA:**

Siguiendo las indicaciones de @RafaelM he puesto "secure": false, pero me sigue dando error. En la petición get no tiene nada en la cabecera, como se puede ver en esta pantalla de postman:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la parte de Angular, me aparece como si estuviera realizando la llama a localhost:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El detalle del error es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Datos de package.json y mensajes de carga**

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "madrid-ocio-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host=0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0-next.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

Datos de carga

```
npm run start

> madrid-ocio-app@0.0.0 start MadridOcioApp
> ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host=0.0.0.0

WARNING: This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications    
locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

Binding this server to an open connection can result in compromising your application or 
computer. Using a different host than the one passed to the "--host" flag might result in
websocket connection issues. You might need to use "--disableHostCheck" if that's the    
case.

chunk {ayuntamiento-ayutamiento-module} ayuntamiento-ayutamiento-module.js, ayuntamiento-ayutamiento-module.js.map (ayuntamiento-ayutamiento-module) 23 kB  [rendered]
chunk {comunidad-comunidad-module} comunidad-comunidad-module.js, comunidad-comunidad-module.js.map (comunidad-comunidad-module) 8.34 kB  [rendered]
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 27.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 141 kB [initial] [rendered]      
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 9.09 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 12.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 2.75 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2021-07-20T18:56:25.075Z - Hash: e0235d08f7f633a6be90 - Time: 9059ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on 0.0.0.0:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
: Compiled successfully.
```

Muchas gracias,

Comment: Probas con la propieda "secure": false ?? Si no comprueba las cabeceras de cada petición e igual podemos intuir por donde va el error en caso de no ser iguales

Comment: Hola @RafaelM. Voy a actualizarlo en la descripción de la pregunta.

Comment: Pero ahi no da error de cors, dice not found... esta bien la ruta a la api?

Comment: El error que me daba al principio, cuando no utilizaba proxy y hacía llamada al Endpoint https://datos.madrid.es con get era el siguiente "Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en https://datos.madrid.es/ (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin')."

Comment: No puedes controlar ese servidor, pero si puedes controlar tu backend. Por que no haces un método en tu backend que sea "transparente" y haga estas peticiones por ti?. Puedes mandarle la construcción de la url por parametro y así solo tienes que lidiar con tu servidor.

Comment: Que tu proxy agregue el http header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: Hola Legna. En el caso de esta aplicación, no tengo backend propiamente dicho, ya que sólo voy a tener la aplicación de Angular con la llamada a este API, y una capa de bootsrap para pintar los datos. @Juan Carlos Guibovich, ¿Cómo se puede hacer eso? Nunca he hecho un proxy y he tirado de lo que he leído en otras respuestas de este foro.

Comment: Hola @Juan Carlos Guibovich. He añadido esos datos en la pregunta, los he puesto por el final.

Comment: He quitado el parámetro de --host=0.0.0.0 del ng serve. El proxy.conf.json está al principio de la pregunta (la invocación desde los scripts de angular.json queda así "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"). Sigue apareciéndome error de CORS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente tu código es correcto. El problema que tienes, que me parece no vas a encontrar solución conectandote via javascript desde el cliente, se produce por la url a la que estás llamando: `https://datos.madrid.es`. El hecho es que como tienes en un proxy.conf.json: `/api`, entonces, cuando utilizas `http://localhost:4200/api` realmente vas a ir a `https://datos.madrid.es/api` y efectivamente se va hacia ese url, pero no devuelve ninguna página sino un HTTP STATUS 301. Junto a este estado manda el `location` real de la pagina a la que quieres llegar y este es la causa del bloqueo del `CORS`. El url `http://localhost:4200/api`  te lleva a `https://datos.madrid.es/api` pero retorna con un estado 301 para redirigir a: `https://datos.madrid.es/portal/site/egob/menuitem.214413fe61bdd68a53318ba0a8a409a0/?vgnextoid=b07e0f7c5ff9e510VgnVCM1000008a4a900aRCRD&vgnextchannel=b07e0f7c5ff9e510VgnVCM1000008a4a900aRCRD&vgnextfmt=default` y aqui se produce el cambio de origen ya que sigues en `http://localhost:4200/api` y no lo vas a poder controlar porque lo resuelve el navegador. Tendrias que cambiar el `url` por este ultimo, pero tampoco te va a servir porque las `apis` están en un iframe.

Salvo que consigas el URL correcto que te lleve sin redirecciones a la pagina, entonces, no hay problema.

Si quieres verificar, trata desde tu programa ir a "/api/xxx" vas a ver que no se produce el CORS pero te devuelve una pagina de "No encontrado".

No obstante lo anterior y como solución alternativa a tu problema, lo que podrías hacer es traerte el .json con las descripciones de todas las `apis`. Solo tendrias que cambiar tu proxy.conf.json por este:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://datos.madrid.es/egobfiles/api.datos.madrid.es.json",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
     "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Con el archivo `json` que recuperes puedes parsearlo y utiliarlo para buscar tus apis. El `api` lo tienes que sobreescribir para que no lo agregue al target.

Espero te sirva.